# Django Permanent Model - how to keep deleted objects in admin change view?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using this package to provide soft delete logic.
https://github.com/MnogoByte/django-permanent

```
class ExternalSystem(PermanentModel):
  full_name = models.CharField()

class Fact(PermanentModel):
  external_system = models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

So, if I "delete" ExternalSystem, in Fact admin change view I see "-" in ExternalSystem field. FK is kept, but ExternalSystem object isn't accessable by default manager.

The only way I found to fix it - is to change FactEditForm:

```
external_system = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ExternalSystem.all_objects.all())
```

However, I have to make such changes in ten+ forms. And I also have to override logic to separate two forms - Edit and Create - because "deleted" objects not supposed to be in CreateForm. But they must remain in ChangeForm for history reasons.

Is there any other way?